# Source code for Ubuntu

Tags: customization, source-code, source

So I wanted to know where the source code is. I know how to get the .ISO file but how can I see or change the code? My goal is to make a Custom OS based on Ubuntu. How can I see the code of .ISO file and are there any documentation on Ubuntu source code?

Comment: Ubuntu is open source as far as I know

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/  Mind though... you need an ISO with the SERVER edition to create a personal Ubuntu You do not need the source code... since you'd be making the desktop yourself :)

Comment: It does not unfortunately

Comment: Oh yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Linux kernel, you can get this from the Linux Kernel Archive: https://www.kernel.org/

Here you will find the kernel code for all the Linux distributions. You can download them, compile them (it does take time!) and load new kernels.

You can look at this link, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel which will tell you how to rebuild your kernel from source and lead you to where Canonical stores its source code.